# Added user association but still getting "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been working on this for many hours now and have started over several times (from a backup point) trying to figure out the problem.

I am trying to add comments to posts. Comments work fine, it's getting the username and avatar to show up that's not working. Here is what I did step by step.

1) `rails g model Comment body:text user:references post:references`

2) I verified that the model was correct

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

3) `rake db:migrate`

4) Added `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy` to both user.rb and post.rb

5) Added `resources :comments` to my routes.

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
    member do
      post '/like' => 'posts#like'
    end
  end
```

6) Generated comments controller `rails g controller comments`

7) Altered the comments the comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      # something else
    end
  end
end
```

8) Created two partials "_comment.html.erb" and "_form.html.erb" in comments' view folder.

"_comment.html.erb"

```
<h2><%= @comment.user.name %></h2>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
```

"_form.html.erb"

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

9) Added comments to posts' show page

```
<h4><%= @post.comments.count %> comments</h4>
<%= render @post.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment</h2>
<%= render "comments/form"%>
```

10) Restarted server

11) Tried to create a comment and got the following error:

> NoMethodError in Posts#show
>
> undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

```
 <h2><%= @comment.user.name %></h2> #THIS LINE IS THE ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

First gotcha, You are creating your comment and thus just assigning user and that is never saved. Change your code to look like

```
@comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment].permit(:body))
@comment.user = current_user
if @comment.save
# rest of code
```

This way the user gets set before the comment is saved. You can also add a validation to the comment model to ensure that a user is present. That way you don't get `nil` in the `user_id` field.

It would also help if we see your show action...`@comment` seems not to have been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The error `undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass` means that your `@comment` is uninitialized (`@comment = nil`), and of course `nil` has no `user` method. Maybe you haven't defined any `@comment` in your `show` action of your `CommentsController`. Update your `show` action to have some `@comment` inside.